# Trading view chart toggle Featuresets on fly

Tags: tradingview-api

How do I enable or disable features on the fly without reinitializing the entire chart instance, I want to add this behavior at click of a button

```
**<script>
new TradingView.widget({
    container: 'chartContainer',
    locale: 'en',
    library_path: 'charting_library/',
    datafeed: new Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed("https://demo-feed-data.tradingview.com"),
    symbol: 'AAPL',
    interval: '1D',
    enabled_features: ["show_spread_operators"], <- on fly 
    disabled_features: ["items_favoriting", "show_object_tree"] <- on fly
});
```

[Link to doc](https://tradingview.com/charting-library-docs/latest/customization/Featuresets/)